# When opening sqlite getting an exception android

Tags: android, sqlite

I had created database in my android app, then inserted a statement. Everything worked, so i wanted to get my database fro MY_PACKAGE/databses/ and copy it to sd card to be reachable.

This worked, but when i trying to open with my sqlite Firefox plugin i get this error:

```
SQLiteManager: Error in opening file Datas.sqlite - either the file is encrypted or corrupt
Exception Name: NS_ERROR_FILE_CORRUPTED
Exception Message: Component returned failure code: 0x8052000b (NS_ERROR_FILE_CORRUPTED) [mozIStorageService.openUnsharedDatabase]
```

Maybe i have to open with something else or i can't open this so easily ?

I will give all the code i used:

Handling my db i used all this code:

[Using your own SQLite database in Android applications](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/)

Copying it to sd card this method:

```
public static boolean backUpDataBase(Context context) {

        final String DATABASE_NAME = "Data.sqlite";
        final String DATABASE_NAME_FULL = "/data/data/package/databases/"
                + DATABASE_NAME;
        boolean result = true;

        // Source path in the application database folder
        String appDbPath = DATABASE_NAME_FULL;

        // Destination Path to the sdcard app folder
        String sdFolder = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "Datas.sqlite";

        File f = new File(sdFolder);
        // if (!f.exists()) {
        // f.mkdir();
        // }

        InputStream myInput = null;
        OutputStream myOutput = null;
        try {
            // Open your local db as the input stream
            myInput = new FileInputStream(appDbPath);
            // Open the empty db as the output stream
            myOutput = new FileOutputStream(f);

            // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            result = false;
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                // Close the streams
                if (myOutput != null) {
                    myOutput.flush();
                    myOutput.close();
                }
                if (myInput != null) {
                    myInput.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

My database looks like this:
2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE "Test" ("_id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL  UNIQUE , "Info" TEXT)

CREATE TABLE "android_metadata" ("locale" TEXT DEFAULT 'en_US')
```

And code to do all i need:

//return databse which is read and write
    DataBaseHelper dataBase= Main.createOrOpenDB(mContext);

```
        Main.backUpDataBase(mContext);

        db = dataBase.myDataBase;

        // Step 1: Inflate layout
        setContentView(R.layout.tabs_fragment_activity);

        try{
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +"Test" +" Values ('1','Inserted');");
        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

So where is wrong, as insert works fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like there is a problem in your code to write it to the SD card (which I'm not seeing immediately).

I wonder, why are you copying it to the SDCard?  It sounds like you merely want to check the file...

If that's actually your goal, then I would recommend running the emulator and simply using the DDMS view from eclipse, navigate to the file and click the button in the upper right corner whose tool-tip says "Pull a file from the device".  What you get in the emulator should be exactly what you get on your phone.

Answer (score 0):

try to use [SQLiteOpenHelper | Android Developers](https://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html&ei=hWmVT-bIMaXW0QXW4_D8AQ&usg=AFQjCNEBb8YvlGxrEdTTNAan7LjslOLlYQ&sig2=3CZGyukB_mcBe5doXDhOQA)